# How do I iterate through folders to find particular files in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through folders to perform analysis on particular files.

Let's say I have 3 Folders named `S1`, `S2`, and `S3`. Each folder contains a file with the same name, called `hi.csv`. Once I get the script to successfully iterate through each folder and find that file, I will have it analyze the CSV and create a new CSV file in each folder.

In lieu of the analysis code, I've just tried to print the files in the first instance. Ideally, I would see a file name called `hi.txt` under each subfolder, `S1`, `S2` and `S3`.

Here is what I've tried so far, but it isn't working:

```
fn = 'hi.txt'
indir = '/Users/sheena/Desktop/Test'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    for d in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(fn):
            print(f)
```

Comment: Any advance on *"isn't working"*?

Comment: You need to provide more information as to what the question actually is, and what you've tried, and what failed. Otherwise it's apt to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check for a certain filename, you should check it in `filenames` and if it is a success, the current folder is `root`. `dirs` doesn't enter the picture.

```
fn = 'hi.txt'
indir = '/Users/sheena/Desktop/Test'
for root, _, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    if fn in filenames:
        print("Got: {}/{}".format(root, fn))
```

See if it works the way you want. Please comment if it doesn't.

Comment: doh great answer ... and OP should probably accept this one +1 Im not sure what I was thinking iterating the filenames directly

Comment: @JoranBeasley except for that redundant step your code is correct. But the thing is I have answered similar questions more than 3 times on SO and for some reason many people are confused about `root` and `dirnames`, basically about what `os.walk` returns.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to see what's going wrong is to add a line

```
print(root, dirs, filenames)
```

just after the first 'for' loop. The output you'll get is something along the lines of

```
/tmp ['s3', 's2', 's1', ...] ['test.py', 'GRADUATE BALLOT APPLICATION FORM 2016-17.doc', 'ankid6955d9721560531274cb8f50ff595a9bd39d66f', '.X0-lock']
/tmp/s3 [] ['hi.txt']
/tmp/s2 [] ['hi.txt']
/tmp/s1 [] ['hi.txt']
/tmp/hsperfdata_joshua [] ['391']
/tmp/cujc ['foo'] []
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-joshua [] []
/tmp/.Test-unix [] []
/tmp/.font-unix [] []
/tmp/.XIM-unix [] []
```

So

1. "os.walk" may not be doing what you're expecting it to do, it's iterating over all subdirectories and subdirectories of subdirectories (but this isn't an issue for your code, there might just be a smarter/faster way of doing it)
2. All the files are in the "filenames" list - so you're iterating over the wrong list! 'hi.txt' is in the 'filenames' list when 'root' is 'blah/S1', 'blah/S2', or 'blah/S3'.

Answer (score 0):

```
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d,fn)):
```

I guess ... maybe ... this probably is not the best way to find the files that match

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    for fname in filenames:
        if fname == fn:
           print os.path.join(root,fname)
```

is probably a little better

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. With your suggestions, I was able to get to the files I wanted, and now I am trying to analyze those files and then output a file into each folder. I tried:

fn = 'diff.nii'
indir = '/Users/sheena/Desktop/DTI'
for root, _, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    if fn in filenames:
        flt = fsl.FLIRT(bins=640, cost_func='mutualinfo')
        flt.inputs.in_file = 'os.path.join(root,fn)'
        flt.inputs.output_type = "NIFTI_GZ"
I received an error, pasted below. I would be grateful for any suggestions! Thank you!!

Comment: TraitError: The 'in_file' trait of a FLIRTInputSpec instance must be an existing file name, but a value of 'os.path.join(root,fn)' <type 'str'> was specified.

Comment: dont put quotes around `os.path.join...`